# Knockout Bindings using Key value pair Inside foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, breeze

I am working on knockout with *BreezeJs* for retrieving and storing data from my local database. The problem I am facing here is the key value binding inside foreach binding. What I want to do, is **to Display the 'Name' attribute into the text box and after retrieving the corresponding 'Id' attribute from my database.**

> "operator"[successfully accessed from breeze] is a attribute defined in database which have int value 1, hence my text box must display the corresponding value from "operators" [defined in my javascript file]
>   i.e.,"Subtraction" for one record

```
var operators = [
{id: 0, name: 'addition'},
{id: 1, name: 'subtraction'},
{id: 2, name: 'division'},
{id: 3, name: 'multiplication'}
   ];
```

My HTML bindings

```
<div data-bind="foreach: jobs">
      <div>
        <label>FirstNumber :</label>
        <input data-bind="value: first_no" />
    </div>

         <div>
        <label>operator :</label>
         <input type="text" data-bind="text:operators.name, value: $root.operator"/>
    </div>
     <div>
        <label>Second Number:</label>
        <input data-bind="value: second_no" />
    </div><div>
        <label>Result :</label>
        <input data-bind="value: result" />
    </div></div>
```

These `result,second_no,operator,first_no` are the column names in my
 database and `jobs` is an `observableArray`.

I know I am not correct but I need to find some way to figure out the above issue.

**Note:** I am using *breezeJS* to get & store data from database that's why I mentioned a tag of it, though the above problem is of knockout rather than breeze.

Comment: There is no foreach anywhere in your bindings, you're trying to bind the unexistent `name` property from `operators` array... How can we help you if you're not clear?

Comment: now check my mistake in hurry i copied something ,

Comment: if I was using <select> instead of <input> tag i would get the answer but how to do same using <input > tag `<select data-bind="options: $root.operators, optionsText: 'name', optionsValue: 'id', value: 
$root.operator"/>`

Comment: data-bind="value: $root.operators[operator].name"

Comment: Steve : Nopes that doesn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the rest of the code, the biggest issue with your code is using a with binding instead of a foreach. Foreach is used to iterate, with is used to change the context.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: jobs">
      <div>
        <label>FirstNumber :</label>
        <input data-bind="value: first_no" />
    </div>

         <div>
        <label>operator :</label>
         <input type="text" data-bind="text:operators.name, value: $root.operator"/>
    </div>
     <div>
        <label>Second Number:</label>
        <input data-bind="value: second_no" />
    </div><div>
        <label>Result :</label>
        <input data-bind="value: result" />
    </div>
</div>
```